# Load balancing Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-load-balancer

Is there any way to load balance the `Azure Blob Storage` by just using `Azure Load Balancer` and the `Blob Storage` (without needing a service)?

What I'm trying to achieve is to hit a load-balancer url like:

```
https://load-balancer.somerandomazureurl.net
```

Which will route the request to a blob container (with same contents) in either West Europe or Central US data centers depending on the location and the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time - Azure Front Door is the right answer for this question. It allows load-balancing between the storage accounts so for a SPA (Single Page Application) the right solution is to use Azure Front Door and multiple storage accounts in the back-end which are configured to be static websites.

More details are in this answer: [Use Azure Front Door to serve a SPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820971/use-azure-front-door-to-serve-a-spa)

Answer (score 4):

You could not do that using [Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview) since it only could load incoming traffic for Azure VM, VM scale sets or availability sets. Azure blob storage could not be a backend for receiving the incoming traffic from load balancer frontend.

If you want to improve the Azure blob storage response performance, you could enable Azure CDN for the storage account.

> Azure CDN offers developers a global solution for delivering
>   high-bandwidth content. It can cache blobs and static content of
>   compute instances at physical nodes in the United States, Europe,
>   Asia, Australia, and South America.

Also, If you no longer want to cache an object in Azure CDN, you could remove content from Azure CDN.

Quickstart: [Integrate an Azure storage account with Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn)