# Can two blob storages buckets accept the same host header?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Azure blob storage now allow custom domain to enabled for them. For example, if my blob name is : foo.blob.core.windows.net, then we can configure a custom domain, say foo.test.com, so the requests coming from this host header will be accepted by this blob.

However, my question is , what if I have to azure blob: foo1.blob.core.windows.net and foo2.blob.core.windows.net. I want to load balance between them but I want both of them to allow that custom domain: foo.test.com. Is that possible? If there is any document regarding this, it will be helpful, I tried looking for it but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291187/load-balancing-azure-blob-storage) could be helpful.

[Azure application gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) also works for this scenario.

Please let me know if you need any more assistance.